# How can we run the unit tests of civicrm from script?

Tags: phpunit, xdebug, civicrm

I execute this commande line to run a unit tests :

> hatem.hadrich@pc_Hatem_Hadrich:/projet/tools$ php /scripts/phpunit CRM_AllTests

I have this error when i run a unit test from my local instance and i can not find a way to resolve it anyone can help me to fix this bug.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CiviTestSuite' not found in /projet/../civicrm/tests/phpunit/CRM/AllTests.php on line 39
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:569
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() 
phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:115
PHP   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest() 
phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:137
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->loadSuiteClass() 
phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:65
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Runner_StandardTestSuiteLoader->load() 
phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:124
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php:39
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Util/Fileloader.php:38
PHP   9. include_once() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Util/Fileloader.php:56
```

Answer (score 0):

i have find a way to fix this bug, you must require_one for the bootstrap file inside CiviTest :

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', '/path_to_project'); 
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
```